# ¿Porque no me encuentra la barra de busqueda de chrome? AutomationUI C#

Tags: c#

he estado investigando como obtener la URL de una tab chrome pero a mi no me funciona he tratado buscandolo con el **treescope.subtree**, **treescope.Children** ,**treescope.Descendent** y ninguna me encuentra la barra de busqueda superior este es mi codigo:

```
try
        {
            var Elemento = AutomationElement.FocusedElement;
            //Pero aqui no lo encuentra por nombre
            AutomationElement edit = Elemento.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree,
              new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Barra de direcciones y de busqueda", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase));
            if (edit is null)
            {
                //siempre entra aqui y de aqui aprovecho para sacar el nombre de la barra, esto me imprime: Barra de direcciones y de busqueda
                return Elemento.Current.Name;
            }
            return ((ValuePattern)edit.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Excepcion";
        }
```

No uso la condicion de tipo porque si entras a facebook o youtube la barra de busqueda que encuentra es la de la pagina y no la del navegador

```
AutomationElement elm1 = Elemento.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));
```

¿Como puedo encontrar la barra de URL del navegador?

Comment: Porque repites tanto la misma pregunta, estas corriendo el riesgo de que todas terminen cerradas

Comment: @Japv pues porque nadie me ayuda, es algo que me urge y cada vez van saliendo cosas nuevas

Comment: Pues no, tu te crees que la gente tiene que ayudarte a los 5 minutos de publicar, tienes que esperar, el sitio tiene sus reglas, debes esperar a recibir ayuda no duplique más las preguntas o todas terminarán cerradas